# Python tweepy create_tweet get created tweet's id

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy, tweets

I'm creating my first twitter bot and have been successful in creating the tweet. Now I'm trying to get the tweet's id to add to an xml file. I'm able to get an uploaded video's id but having issues getting the created tweet's id.

Snippet of the code (copied from a stackoverflow answer)

```py
import tweepy

def get_twitter_conn_v1(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret) -> tweepy.API:
    """Get twitter conn 1.1"""
    auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, api_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(
        access_token,
        access_token_secret,
    )
    return tweepy.API(auth)

def get_twitter_conn_v2(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret) -> tweepy.Client:
    """Get twitter conn 2.0"""
    client = tweepy.Client(
        consumer_key = api_key,
        consumer_secret = api_secret,
        access_token = access_token,
        access_token_secret = access_token_secret,
    )

    return client

client_v1 = get_twitter_conn_v1(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
client_v2 = get_twitter_conn_v2(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

media = client_v1.media_upload(media_path, chunked=True, media_category='tweet_video')
media_id = media.media_id

tweetText = 'created a tweet'

tweet = client_v2.create_tweet(text=tweetText)
```

removed the addition of the video to the tweet for faster testing.

I can't figure out how to get id of the tweet just created. The tweepy documentation is going over my head. Searched google, only to get results on how to get a tweet via id or get tweets and parse through them.

I tried

```py
tweetID = tweet.id
```

and get the following error

```py
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'id'
```

when I add

```py
print(tweet)
```

I see the following

```py
Response(data={'edit_history_tweet_ids': ['1696308550870671480'], 'id': '1696308550870671480', 'text': .....)
```

It's there just don't know how to get it.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the response.json file is like this:

[image: response.json]

So, to get the Tweet ID, replace:

```py
tweetID = tweet.id
```

with the following line of code:

```py
tweetID = tweet.data['id']
# For integer data type
# tweetID = int(tweet.data['id'])
```

For more information:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/api-reference/post-tweets#tab0

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Just before your post I finally figured it out.

```tweetID = tweet.data.id```
did not work for me but the following did

```tweetID = tweet.data['id']```

Still grateful for your reply.